# Set the AWS console password for IAM user with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I am newbie to the Terraform and just want to ask that is there anyway to set the AWS console password for IAM user with Terraform. I am able to configure the IAM users, group, their access and secret key but couldn't find the way to set the console password. Please point me to where I can get it work. Thanks

Comment: I suppose it is not possible by AWS API or AWS SDK and therefore not supported by Terraform.

Answer (score 10):

Its possible to get console password for IAM USER using terraform :
Using below command :

`terraform output password | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt`

Follow below instructions :

1. Store password in outputs.tf file
2. terraform output password > would give your encrypted password
3. Now before install nodejs and node on your server and set PATH
4. Now to decrypt password we need one more concept that is KEYBASE :                      https://keybase.io/
5. Go this site create a account in KEYBASE from console then under Docs go to Linux/Ubuntu  and follow instructions :
   Now in shell
   keybase login
   enter all details.
6. Point to be noted :

> resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "user_login" {
> user    = "${aws_iam_user.user.name}"
> pgp_key = "keybase:username"  ------------ username means: user you
> created in keybase account
> password_length = 10                       }

Now terraform plan
terraform apply
keybase pgp list
terraform output password | base64 --decode | keybase pgp decrypt

You would get your password :) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can now do so by using the [iam_user_login_profile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user_login_profile.html) resource

```
resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "foo" {
    user    = "${aws_iam_user.bar.name}"
    pgp_key = "${var.key}"
}
```

Note that the `pgp_key` is required and can be either a PGP public key or a reference to a keybase.io profile (say `foobar`) by passing `keybase:foobar` in the `pgp_key` variable.

The [iam_user_login_profile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user_login_profile.html) resource exports a `password` attribute which is the encrypted password for an `aws_iam_user`.

Check the [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user_login_profile.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the password via Terraform isn't really possible. Even if it were, it wouldn't be ideal practice because you'd have a password in the configuration. The better option is to let AWS set/use/create a default password that is given to the specific user in a secure way and ensure that they change it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an article which I wrote about secrets/passwords in the output of terraform. It's in portuguese, but you cant translate:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/secret-keys-passwords-output-t%2525C3%2525A9rcio-campos-swyof%3FtrackingId=k%252B9iDUJWQMGLQmnI04sNJg%253D%253D/?trackingId=k%2B9iDUJWQMGLQmnI04sNJg%3D%3D

I hope this could help someone.