# Terraform provisioned IAM user created with IAM Console access disabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

[image: AWS IAM User Sign-in credentials]

I'm generating credentials via keybase.io PGP in my Terraform config. I can confirm access via aws-cli is successful for the new user.

However, Console access remains disabled. Is there a way to create a user with Terraform with the console access enabled?

I appreciate that's a bit of an anti-pattern for Terraform, but I'd like my new user to be able to log in to the Console UI to validate/debug.

**UPDATE 1**

Terraform module:

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws/0.0.4

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-iam/tree/master/modules/iam-user

user.tf:

```
module "user" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-user"
  name = "user"
  pgp_key = "keybase:foo"
}
```

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code?

Comment: Please see Update 1 in the main body of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable console login using `aws_iam_user_login_profile`. Terraform documentation for this can be found [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user_login_profile.html). You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36565256/set-the-aws-console-password-for-iam-user-with-terraform) stackoverflow question.

Comment: Perfect -- that's exactly what I was missing! Works a charm now, thank you.