# Terraform - AWS IAM user with Programmatic access

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I'm working with [aws](/questions/tagged/aws) via [terraform](/questions/tagged/terraform).
I'm trying to create an IAM user with Access type of "**Programmatic access**".

With the AWS management console this is quite simple:

[image: AWS console management]

When trying with Terraform ([reference to docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_user.html)) it seems that only the following arguments are supported:

```
name
path
permissions_boundary
force_destroy
tags
```

Maybe this should be configured via a policy? 
Any help will be appreciated.

---

(*) [Related  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353521/terraform-provisioned-iam-user-created-with-iam-console-access-disabled) with different scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `aws_iam_access_key` (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_access_key.html) terraform resource to create Access keys for the user and that should imply that user has `Programmatic Access`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeap, this is probably the way. I would expected for a supported argument of "Programmatic Access" (boolean) in the AWS_IAM_USER resource , which will provide the "Access Key" as an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

The `aws_iam_user` resource needs to also have an [`aws_iam_access_key`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_access_key.html) resource created for it.

The [iam-user](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws/2.3.0/submodules/iam-user) module has [a comprehensive example](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-iam/blob/12c846b6cf875c5d975742dcb249fc42b3f1a18a/modules/iam-user/main.tf) of using it.

You could also use that module straight from the registry and let that do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to encrypt and just looking for **Access key** & **Secret key** into **plain text** you can use this

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_iam_access_key" "sagemaker" {
  user    = aws_iam_user.user.name
}

resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  name = "user-name"
  path = "/"
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "sagemaker_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSageMakerFullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "attach-policy" {
  name       = "sagemaker-policy-attachment"
  users      = [aws_iam_user.user.name]
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.sagemaker_policy.arn
}
```

**output.tf**

```
output "secret_key" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.user.secret
}


output "access_key" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.user.id
}
```

you will get the **Access key** and **secret key** into the **plain text** you can directly use it.